# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'val'

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to achieve jQuery validation. The scenario is if a field is empty it will give a required message error. If not empty and input is invalid it will give a specific error message for each field. With my current code I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'val'

Any hints for solving this? Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/PDjwZ/4/

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name.val()) && name.val() != emptyerror) {
    name.addClass("needsfilled");
    name.val(nameerror);
}
```

Comment: Your code in JSFiddle does not throw any exception

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PDjwZ/4/show/  > click on submit . check console in chrome browser.

Comment: Than name may be a `DOM` object..try `console.log(name)` in  firefox to see whats in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited (after view fiddle):

It seems that you aren't using `var` when declaring your variables. I've edited the fiddle to change `name = $("#name")` to `var name = $("#name")`. Seems like the variable name is conflicting with some other (global) variable.

Comment: if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(mobile.val()) && mobile.val() != emptyerror && mobile.val().length != 10) {
            mobile.addClass("needsfilled");
            mobile.val(mobileerror);
        }

Comment: @mkat All your variables should be using `var`

Comment: hy can u check if i input aaaaaaaaaa in mobile field it doesn't throwing any error .where it must.

Comment: The problem is with the test: `if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(mobile.val()) && mobile.val() != emptyerror && mobile.val().length != 10)` should be `if ((!/^[0-9]+$/.test(mobile.val()) && mobile.val() != emptyerror) || mobile.val().length != 10)`

Comment: yeah i got that thanx buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your variables properly; they're going to the global namespace. See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDjwZ/8/).

e.g.

```
var name = $("#name");
```

Comment: Oops, armen beat me to it- but to be fair, he edit-ninja'd ;)

Comment: if (!/^[0-9]+$/.test(mobile.val()) && mobile.val() != emptyerror && mobile.val().length != 10) {
            mobile.addClass("needsfilled");
            mobile.val(mobileerror);
        }hy can u check if i input aaaaaaaaaa in mobile field it doesn't throwing any error .where it must.